# How to access a json array in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays, json

I'm using this html and javascript to send json data to my php file. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/9aWNj/

How to access it from there in php to echo out a given element?

Something along the lines of:

```
$value = json_decode($_POST["newOrder"])
echo $value[1];
```

etc

I'm not sure how to retrieve data from this.

Comment: My code is here -> jsbin.com/igewiv/1/edit and hosted on a php server -> top50.zxq.net/fiddle.php. I'm trying just to be able to echo a selected element and their position i.e. 2 in position 1 or whatever it may be. so I know I can store them in a db etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle to see how the javascript should be in case you're still lost: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9aWNj/3/

this is your data decoded by php:

```
`stdClass Object ( [order] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 6 [5] => 7 [6] => 8 [7] => 9 [8] => 10 [9] => 11 [10] => 1 [11] => 12 ) )`
```

To access it it will be: example:

```
 $order_0=$value->order[0];
 $order_1=$value->order[1];
```

Or you use the true for json_decode and it will become like this

```
 $order_0=$value['order'][0];
 $order_1=$value['order'][1];
```

Comment: I've tried $value = json_decode($_POST["newOrder"], true);
echo $order_0=$value['order'][0]; and not had any output from it, is there a problem with this code or a problem elsewhere?

Comment: you can't echo $order_0=$value['order'][0]; it should be 2 lines: $order_0=$value['order'][0]; echo $order_0;

Comment: I'm still not receiving any output from this. My code is here -> http://jsbin.com/igewiv/1/edit and hosted on a php server -> http://top50.zxq.net/fiddle.php. I'm trying just to be able to echo a selected element and their position i.e. 2 in position 1 or whatever it may be. so I know I can store them in a db etc.

Comment: can you update your question to show us what exactly are you doing please.

Comment: I don't understand, how is your php now?

Comment: There is no response from the echo call, I'm sure if the data isn't being passed correctly from the javascript or if I'm accessing it incorrectly in php.

Comment: this: $value = json_decode($_POST["newOrder"]) should be $value = json_decode($_POST["dataStr"])

Comment: Still not getting any output from $value = json_decode($_POST["dataStr"]);
$order_0=$value['order'][0];
echo $order_0;

Comment: sorry my mistake, in your ajax call you're keeping dataStr empty replace data: dateStr by data: "dataStr="+dataStr

Comment: I'm still not getting any return from the echo using this. This is the code + php I've used. http://jsfiddle.net/2FUUC/

Comment: where are you waiting for your response btw? it won't come anywhere in the browser where you can see it, unless you check in the console

Comment: add this success : function (data){alert(data);}, before url: don't forget the comma after the }

Comment: Why wouldn't it return in an echo if its in a string format? If it doesn't how else could I get the data for inserting into a db? Using the success function shows a popup window of the page's html, not sure if thats the intended result or not.

Comment: well at the place of the echo of the values, you can do whatever you want with the data in the php script insert them into the database or whatever... the pop up was just for you to see.

Comment: I know that but if I can't access them to echo I'm assuming the data isn't there or not in the form that I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It may helpful

```
$FP=fopen(JSON_DIR."JsonArray.txt",'r');
$J_ARRAY=fread($FP,filesize(JSON_DIR."JsonArray.txt"));
$J_ARRAY=json_decode($J_ARRAY,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$value = json_decode($_POST["newOrder"], true)
echo "<pre>";
print_r($value);
```

Note the second parameter `true`, that gives you output as array else it will be object.

Answer (score 0):

Check the php manual.

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns an object as default. use a second param true to return an array.

```
json_decode($_POST["newOrder"], true)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use json in PHP like I think you might want to then I suggest you put a true in the json_decode function.

This will give you the following:

```
$json = json_decode($data,true); 
$json["sub-values"]["sub thing"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to send the JSON as a body of POST request? Do it simpler:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<url_to_php_file>",
    type: "POST",
    data: { order: JSON.stringify(dataArr) }
});
```

And on the server side use:

```
$value = json_decode($_POST["order"]);
echo $value[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Json_decode return result as object by default, to get array you need to put second parameter to true.

$data = json_decode($_POST["newOrder"], false); return result as object

for printing object use

echo $data->something;

$data = json_decode($_POST["newOrder"], true); return result as array

for printing array use

echo $data['something'];